# php array merge with value of parent array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I need to merge an array with value of parent array.

```
$testArr=unserialize('a:6:{s:5:"queue";a:2:{i:6;s:1:"5";i:5;s:1:"2";}s:3:"sum";a:2:{i:6;s:3:"765";i:5;s:3:"2.1";}s:7:"sumAccD";a:2:{i:6;s:3:"543";i:5;s:3:"3.1";}s:7:"sumAccC";a:2:{i:6;s:2:"54";i:5;s:3:"3.3";}s:7:"comment";a:2:{i:6;s:12:"test comment";i:5;s:6:"111222";}s:3:"yt0";s:0:"";}');

$ret = array();
foreach ($testArr as $pkey => $pval) {
if (is_array($pval)) {
    foreach ($pval as $pvkey => $pvval) {
        $ret[$pvkey] = array($pkey => $pvval);
    }
}
}
echo '<pre>', print_r($ret), '</pre>';
```

In this case it prints out

```
Array
(
[6] => Array
    (
        [comment] => test comment
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [comment] => 111222
    )

)
1
```

Unfortunally it print out only comment. I need to add other rows: queue,sum,sumAccD,sumAccC. Array must look like this:

```
Array
(
[6] => Array
    (
        [queue] => 5
        [sum] => ''
        ....
        [comment] => test comment
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [queue] => 2
        [sum] => 2.1
        ....
        [comment] => 111222
    )

)
1
```

Please help merge them.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by replacing

```
$ret[$pvkey] = array($pkey => $pvval);
```

with

```
$ret[$pvkey][$pkey] = $pvval;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
$ret[$pvkey] = array($pkey => $pvval);
```

You're assigning the key to a new array every time, overwriting what was previously there.
In your case, 'comment' is the last key that is processed, so that's going to be the only key in the final array.

Instead of this, you could define a new array only once outside the inner for, like this:

```
$ret[$pvkey] = array();
```

And then assign your values to that array in the inner for loop as you would normally do (so no more creating arrays there!)

Comment: When I trying to merge them with:
    $ret[$pvkey] .= array($pkey => $pvval);
it prints 
    [6] => ArrayArrayArrayArrayArray
    [5] => ArrayArrayArrayArrayArray

Comment: That's because `.` is the string concatenation operator, and thus converts both operands to a string. Arrays converted to strings are 'Array' in PHP. You can merge arrays with `+=`, though.

Comment: Problem solved by replacing 

$ret[$pvkey] = array($pkey => $pvval);

with

$ret[$pvkey][$pkey] = $pvval;